# Pointer from vector causes BAD_ACCESS error when created from object reference

Tags: c++

I have a use case where I need to store pointers to object in vector

```
class Foo {
   void hello() {}
}

vector<Foo*> my_vector


// There is an object up the chain that takes in Foo

bar.setFoo(Foo())

void setFoo(Foo foo) {
   my_vector.emplace_back(&foo);  
}
// down the chain

my_vector[0]->hello() // Throws BAD_ACCESS as I see there is nothing in memory address
```

For Testing if I change to this it works fine:

```
// change setFoo to take a pointer
bar.setFoo(new Foo());

void setFoo(Foo *foo) {
   my_vector.emplace_back(foo);
} 

my_vector[0]->hello() // works
```

I cannot really use new Foo as I don't control that interface plus have to manually delete

How can I come up with a solution where I can create vector of pointers from object references and safely use them

Comment: `void setFoo(Foo foo) { my_vector.emplace_back(&foo); }` -- And poof into a puff of smoke goes the temporary you're storing the pointer of.

Answer (score 2):

Because your `setFoo` function takes its argument by value, that argument is a local variable. A variable whose life-time ends immediately when the function returns.

The pointer you save in the vector will become invalid as soon as `setFoo` returns. Dereferencing that pointer leads to *undefined behavior*.

The natural solution is to *not* store pointers in the vector. And if it's a requirement then you need to allocate the objects dynamically.

My recommendation if you must use pointers (for example because of polymorphism) is to use a *smart pointer* like [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr).

Also even with pointer you *can* pass the argument to `setFoo` by value, using copy-semantics:

```
vector<std::unique_ptr<Foo>> my_vector;

void setFoo(Foo foo) {
    my_vector.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Foo>(foo));
}
```

Comment: Yeah its a requirement as It's really a vector of Foo parent class pointer Foo is templated. Its really std::any kind of implementation in c++ 11 , allows me to store random objects in that vector. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: @at_123 You should post those details in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your code snippet that is producing the error?

At a glance, it looks like this function may not be working since you are storing the address of a Foo object that goes out of scope

```
void setFoo(Foo foo) {
   my_vector.emplace_back(&foo);  
}
```

This second one probably works because you are creating Foo dynamically (from the heap) somewhere else

```
void setFoo(Foo *foo) {
   my_vector.emplace_back(foo);
}
```

Above, you are storing the address.  If you are performing your clean up (deleting foo) somewhere else, then you won't need to clean it up here.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I come up with a solution where I can create vector of
> pointers from object references and safely use them

You can use [`std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Foo>>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr).

Here is an example:

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class Foo 
{
    public:
      virtual ~Foo() {}
      virtual void hello() { std::cout << "Hello\n"; }
};

class Foo2 : public Foo
{
    public:
      void hello() { std::cout << "Hello2\n"; }
};

std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Foo>> my_vector;

template <typename T>
void addFoo(const T& f)
{
    auto ptr = std::make_unique<T>(f);
    my_vector.emplace_back(std::move(ptr));
}

int main()
{
    Foo fBase;
    Foo2 fDerived;
    addFoo(fBase);
    addFoo(fDerived);
    for (auto& v : my_vector)
       v->hello();
}
```

Output:

```
Hello
Hello2
```

At the end, the pointers are automatically deleted.  If you require pointers to be shared, then use `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Foo>>`.